# listing all packages not used after date

Tags: apt, kubuntu, 19.04

I remember when I used fedora, I could list all packages that I hadn't used for a while with a command like this:

```
# rpmorphan --all --access-time 10
```

where 10 is ten days. is there any apt command or snippet that can do this? I've looked over three pages of google results and found nothing

Comment: I've used apt for over a decade, and never seen any function of apt that tracks usage.

Comment: According to rpmorphan.sourceforge.net, `rpmorphan` *"intends to be clone of deborphan Debian tools for rpm packages"* - however I don't see any mention of access time in the `deborphan` man page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [deborphan](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/deborphan.1.html), however it does not support anything similar to `--access-time`.

However there is also [popularity-contest](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/popularity-contest.8.html).

> The popularity-contest command gathers information about Debian packages installed on the system, and prints the name of the most recently used executable program in  that  package **as  well  as  its  last-accessed  time  (atime) and last-attribute-changed time (ctime)** to stdout.

This is an opt-out by default option in Ubuntu, inherited from Debian, as it sends data on what packages you use to Debian servers with `/usr/share/popularity-contest/popcon-upload`.

You can read about it here: https://popcon.debian.org/README

Anyway you can use it to achieve your goal. The idea is described here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483900/how-to-find-unused-packages-in-debian

However if you don't want your packages stats to be sent to Debian (accidentally or not), you should better make some steps to prevent it.

I.e. you can block `popcon.debian.org` in `/etc/hosts`.

First edit `/etc/hosts` with:

```
sudo editor /etc/hosts
```

and add this line into it:

> 127.0.0.1 popcon.debian.org

Also you can replace `/usr/share/popularity-contest/popcon-upload` with some dummy script.

First wipe it with:

```
echo -n ""  | sudo tee /usr/share/popularity-contest/popcon-upload
```

Then edit:

```
sudo editor /usr/share/popularity-contest/popcon-upload
```

And save it with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 0
```

Keep in mind that these changes won't be permanent and the mentioned file might get replaces with future upgrades.